# PMI calculation for Integer Features

Tags: python

I am working on a dataset that has numeric features and I want to compute the PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) for the features.

For example, I have the following:

```
test_features = [[1,1], [1,0], [0,1], [0,0]]
test_labels = [1,1,0,0]
```

Where the target class is 1.

How can PMI be computed in this situation?

Edit:

The expected output: a dictionary of the form {feature: ppmi} where each feature is denoted by its ID (position in the 1-hot encoded representatoin)

Comment: you need to be more specific when posting questions. For eg: post the expected output?

Comment: Thank you Neeraj, I have edited the post to add the expected output

Comment: whats the test_labels for? im assuming you need to calculate pmi using log formula on [1,1], [1,0] so on for data in test_features?

Comment: TO provide more background - I nee to compute PMI which is defined as a function to compute the pointwise mutual information between all features in the data set and target class of interest
Input: - features for N input instances
       - labels for N input instances
       - target feature value (default=1)
       - target class